# A conjecture based on Wilson's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

**Definitions:**

Lagrange's theorem implies that for each prime $p$, the factors of $(p − 1)!$ can be arranged in unequal pairs, with the exception of $±1$, where the product of each pair $≡ 1 \pmod p$. *[See Wiki article on Wilson's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Prime_modulus)*

From the example in the link above, for $p=11$ we have

$$(11-1)!=[(1\cdot10)]\cdot[(2\cdot6)(3\cdot4)(5\cdot9)(7\cdot8)]  \equiv [-1]\cdot[1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1]  \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$$

Let the products of the pairs that $≡ 1 \pmod p$ be the multiset $A_p$, and $A_{p_n}$ the multiset for the $n$th prime.

For the above example then, $A_{p_5}=\{(2\cdot6),(3\cdot4),(5\cdot9),(7\cdot8)\}=\{12,12,45,56\}$.

**Conjecture:**

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k \in A_{p_n}}(k-1)}{(p_n)^3}\approx\frac18$$

where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.

**Examples:**

For $p=11$ we have

$$\dfrac{11+11+44+55}{11^3}=\dfrac{1}{11}$$

For $p=997$ we have

$$\dfrac{123218233}{997^3}=\dfrac{123218233}{991026973}$$

**Comments:**

As @YCor noted below, the $-1$ in the $k-1$ can be removed, since its contribution tends to $0$. The conjecture can therefore be simplified to

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k \in A_{p_n}}k}{(p_n)^3}\approx\frac18$$

I have no idea whether the above statement is correct, or how to go about trying to find a proof. Any comments on the any of the above are most welcome.

Comment: You might as well take that $P_n$ outside the $\sum$.

Comment: You might as well write it as $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k \in A}k-1}{(p_n)^3}\approx\frac18$.

Comment: You can't say $A$ is a set, since you take multiplicities into account. Also you should denote it as $A_p$ and write $A_{p_n}$ instead of $A$ in the conjecture.

Comment: @YCor ok, will alter, but what should I call $A_p$ if not a set?

Comment: Because as a set, $\{12,12,45,56\}=\{12,45,56\}$.

Comment: Also the original formulation with $(k-1)/p_n$ was natural because this quotient is indeed an integer. In the new formulation, the $-1$ in $k-1$ seems artificial and can be removed since its contribution tends to 0. Second, the sum $\sum_A k$ is indexed by a quotient set of $\{2,\dots,p-2\}$ (modded out by the inverse involution). An alternative is to denote by $c_i$ the inverse of $i$ mod $p$ in $\{1,\dots,p-1\}$ and write the sum as $\frac12\sum_{2\le i\le p-2}ic_i$.

Comment: It might help to note that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n/2}k(n-k)-1}{n^3} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: With @YCor's notation, if it's reasonable to assume that $i$ and $c_i$ behave roughly independently then one would have $\frac1p \sum i c_i \approx \left(\frac1p \sum i\right) \left(\frac1p \sum c_i\right) \approx p^2/4$, so this heuristically justifies the $1/8$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For an integer $n$ with $1\leq n\leq p-1$, let $n^{-1}$ be the inverse of $n$ modulo $p$. It follows from Weil's bound on Kloosterman sums that for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{n: xp\leq n\leq (x+\epsilon) p, yp\leq n^{-1}<(y+\epsilon) p\}$ has cardinality $\epsilon^2p+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p}\log^2 p)$. Hence up to a relative error tending to 0 the sum in question can be replaced by an integral, that is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{p-1} n\cdot n^{-1} \sim p^3\int_0^1\int_0^1 xy\;dx\;dy = \frac{p^3}{4}.
$$
(Note that the $\cdot$ on the left hand side refers to the multiplication of integers, not to modular multiplication). Here each pair $(a,b)$ with $ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is counted twice, with the exception of $(1,1)$ and $(-1, -1)$, which contribute less than $p^2$. Hence up to an error $\mathcal{O}(p^2)$ the left hand side of the above expression is twice $\sum_{k\in A} k$, which proves your claim.

Comment: How can you get $O(\sqrt{p}\log p)$? I can prove asymptotic formula only with $O(\sqrt{p}\log^2 p)$.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking in one dimension. I corrected the error term to $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p}\log^2 p)$.

Comment: But your error term can be valid. In the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/175822/incomplete-kloosterman-sum the error term was $O(\sqrt{p}\log p)$ indeed. In the case $f(x,y)=xy$ situation can be similar.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov certainly $O(\sqrt{p}\log p)$ *looks* feasible: [*plot 1*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqAz.png), [*plot 2*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4fih.png)
where first plot is $\left(\left(p_n/2\right)^3-\sum\limits_{k \in A_{p_n}}{k}\right)/\left(p_n^{5/2}\log p_n\right),$ second is $ \text{expr.} ~/\left(p_n ^{5/2}\log^{2} p_n\right).$

Comment: @martin Thank you for calculations, probably $O(\sqrt p\log p)$ is a right order for error term.

Answer (score 11):

If $f(x,y)$ is a "good" function, then
$$\sum_{xy\equiv 1\mod p}f(x,y)=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{x,y=0}^{p-1}f(x,y)-R_p[f],$$
where $R_p[f]$ is a "small" error term (see Lemma 5 [here](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth13_eng.pdf)). In your case $f(x,y)=xy$, so the main term is $p^3/4.$  Usually $R_p[f]=O(p^{1/2+\varepsilon}\|f\|)$ while the main term is like $p\|f\|$. In this case error term is $O(p^{5/2+\varepsilon}).$

This observation has a lot of applications in problems connected with lattices (because bases are parametrized by equation $ad-bc=n$, so $ad\equiv n\mod b$ ).

Comment: thanks for the great answer! So in this case
$$\left(p_n/2\right)^3-\sum\limits_{k \in A_{p_n}}{k}=\mathcal{O}\left(p_n\ ^{5/2}\right)$$?

Comment: Yes. But it must be $O(p_n^{5/2}\log^2p_n)$ instead of $O(p_n^{5/2})$.

Comment: And this $\log$ is impotant because usually (numerically, it is not proved) normalized error term (in our case $R_p\cdot p^{-5/2}$) is gaussian i.e. unbounded.

Comment: I find your main formula very interesting. What is its "history"? Can it be traced back in the literature to more specific instances? And could you point to any simple example of its use in a lattice-connected problem? (The simpler, the better).

Comment: Also, does this example actually satisfy the finite difference conditions on your Lemma 5, or perhaps they can be exchanged for others? If I'm not mistaken, I get $\Delta_{1,0}=y\geq 0$, $\Delta_{0,1}=x\geq 0$.

Comment: @Jose Brox The "history" goes back to the theory of numerical integration and uniform distribution theory. When you replace given function $f$ by its Fourier series you'll get error term depending on Fourier corfficients of $f$ and trigonometric sums of a given net. This argument was used by Weyl in his pioneer work [Über die Gleichverteilung von Zahlen mod. Eins](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01475864) (1916). Basic latice problem is a distribution of vectors in reduced basis. Conditions from Lemma 5 can be replaced for another ones (see the proof).

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Thanks! Could you please give some nice reference to learn about these techniques for lattices?

Comment: @JoseBrox I applied this technique in Frobenius problem, see [1](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM2009v200n04ABEH004011/meta) and [2](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM2010v074n05ABEH002514/meta). Reduction of Frobenius problem to a lattice proble is described [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS0081543812010245).

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Btw, are you aware of the recent paper by Tripathi with exact formulas for the Frobenius number of three numbers? It is "Formulae for the Frobenius number in three variables", https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16301743

Comment: @JoseBrox Too many formulae within. Looks like Rødseth's formula hidden behind complicated notations.